# API Gateway resources are creating multiple times with terraform without considering state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am implementing API Gateway with Terraform.. When I create first time all path parts and integration/methods are creating as expected. When I run terraform apply again, TF re-creating integration and then re-creating all integration responses. TF not considering state file and creating (destroy and create) multiple times which causes lot of issues.

Did anyone faced this similar issue?

```
 # module.reset-password_options.aws_api_gateway_integration.default must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "default" {
      - cache_key_parameters    = [] -> null
      ~ cache_namespace         = "7cpdkv" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id                      = "agi-4ek66g6ej2-7cpdkv-OPTIONS" -> (known after apply)
      + integration_http_method = "OPTIONS" # forces replacement
      - request_parameters      = {} -> null
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Like above it is changing on every terraform apply.

`Apply complete! Resources: 52 added, 14 changed, 27 destroyed.`

I am using below terraform

**Terraform v1.0.7, provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.59.0**

Comment: It seems like somehow the method name `"OPTIONS"` is being lost here, either by the AWS provider or by the API Gateway API. If you've written `integration_http_method = "OPTIONS"` (or something equivalent to that) and yet this configuration won't converge then I think you've found a bug in the AWS provider, since it should either create the object with that method name _or_ return an error saying it's invalid, depending on the situation.

Comment: The behavior you saw here seems to be tracked in [AWS provider issue #11810](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11810).

Answer (score 1):

If the aws_api_gateway_integration resource is of type "MOCK" AND integration_http_method is set, the AWS API silently ignores the integration_http_method setting. I suppose these combinations are not supported? Then, the next time an apply is run, terraform sees that integration_http_method is not set and recreates the resource. Wash, repeat, because this is never actually set with type == "MOCK".

A solution here is to remove your integration_http_method setting.

See this issue for more info: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11810